# How to retrieve contents of message.json file with chrome.i18n web extension API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

When using chrome's `chrome.i18n` API, the `chrome.i18n.getMessage` method retrieves only one message at a time.

```js
const buttonText = chrome.i18n.getMessage('buttonText');
```

What I want is to update the popup UI when the popup opens with the localized contents of `message.json` file. Doing so requires me to know the message names used. Is there a method/technique similar to `getMessage` for retrieving all the contents of the `message.json` file at once?

Right now, I can only keep all the message names somewhere and retrieve each localized message individually like:

```js
const messages = ["buttonText", "buttonTitle"];

messages.forEach((message) => {
  const messageText = chrome.i18n.getMessage(message);
  // Update UI
});
```

Comment: There's no API but you can use `fetch` or XMLHttpRequest to read the file as json.

Answer (score 0):

To get the "messages.json" file you would have to use "fetch" and access the URL of the file with the ["chrome.runtime" API and the "getURL" method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL).

```
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(`_locales/en/messages.json`))
```

The only thing is that in this way you have to specify the language yourself and verify it, that's how I did it:

```
let lang = 'en';
if (["es"].includes(chrome.i18n.getUILanguage().split('-')[0])) {
    lang = chrome.i18n.getUILanguage().split('-')[0];
}
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(`_locales/${lang}/popup_content.json`))
```

Detecting the language of the browser and verifying if it exists in my extension apart from the default language, in this case English, if it does not exist in the array it is not modified and remains by default.

My "_locales" directory:
_locales -> en -> messages.json 
_locales -> es -> messages.json

Finally, to iterate the result of "messages.json", as it is an object, I found these ways:

```
for (let key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

Both ways iterate and return the keys of the given object. more info: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Final code: this will return each value of the "message" key of each object within the main object of the json.

```
let lang = 'en';
if (["es"].includes(chrome.i18n.getUILanguage().split('-')[0])) {
    lang = chrome.i18n.getUILanguage().split('-')[0];
}
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(`_locales/${lang}/messages.json`)).then(res=> {
    res.json().then(json=> {
        Object.keys(json).forEach(key => {
            console.log(json[key].message);
        });
    });
});
```

The file "_locales -> en -> messages.json":

```
{
  "appName": {
    "message": "Name of my extension"
  },
  "appDesc": {
    "message": "Awesome extension."
  }
}
```

The result in the console will be something like:

> Name of my extension
>
> Awesome extension.

Sorry if the wording is not correct or I am very repetitive, I had to use the translator.